# MySQL add few column exception for TRIGGER UPDATE FOR EACH ROW

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, exception

How to effectively add column `id`, `name` exception for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updated BEFORE UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.date=NOW()
```

so that `date=NOW()` will be affected on updating any column except `id` and `name`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you want to do. Could you rephrase or clarify your question?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347736/mysql-trigger-new-date-now-on-any-columns-update-except-id-and-name

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without knowing what RDBMS you are using or what your table schema looks like. But here is an example for SQL Server.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_MYTABLE_UPDATESTAMP
ON  dbo.[MYTABLE]
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE I SET I.[MyTableUpdateDate] = GETDATE(), I.[MyTableUpdateBy] = SYSTEM_USER
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN [MyTable] T ON T.MyTableId = I.MyTableId
    WHERE IsNull(T.[NumericColumnA], 0) <> IsNull(I.[NumericColumnA], 0)
    OR IsNull(T.[StringColumnB], '') <> IsNull(I.[StringColumnB], '')
    OR IsNull(T.[DateColumnC], '01-01-1950 00:00:00') <> IsNull(I.[DateColumnC], '01-01-1950 00:00:00')
END
GO
```